# Typescript AST parser ignores break lines between sentences

Tags: parsing, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, tslint, typescript-compiler-api

I have a doubt about how to Typescript parse to AST. *My goal is be able to count how many break lines there are between imports and the class declaration.*

I thought would be able to do it using the start and end position of each statement. But, it turns out Typescript parser ignore the break lines.

If the image is not enough clear, I'll point out the **ClassDeclaration** in babylon parser starts at **116** while in typescript parser starts at **113**.

I wonder why this is happening and how to solve it using Typescript or there is any kind of workaround for that? I'm using **tslint** to create a custom *Rule*.

Typescript AST Parser
https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/ffa8dc62cec5bea5a5f76ca978af53b1/306e2bd99d0c2851e41933a2df989ae36a2f4b73

[image: typescript ast]

Babylon7 AST Parser
https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/ffa8dc62cec5bea5a5f76ca978af53b1/d50f63227dec8549a70d6fbb35d4d1aa62b0ea25

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the TS parser to me. Probably best to file a bug.

Comment: @loganfsmyth thanks, I've been waiting for a while and no answer, perhaps you are right.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected. The `pos` property shows the end position of the last significant token. The `node.getStart(sourceFile)` method is what you're interested in and will return the start position.

I suggest using my ast viewer ([ts-ast-viewer](https://ts-ast-viewer.com/)) as it is specialized for the TypeScript compiler API and will show you this information.

Comment: thanks for sharing the link, i completely forgot about that! Have a nice day : )